# How to insert content inside tinymce editor using vue js?

Tags: vue.js, tinymce

I want to insert content like `<span class="some-class">text</span>` inside tinymce editor using a button in vue js template. How could I accomplish that using the [tinymce-vue](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-vue) wrapper?
Here's the code:

```
<template>
  <tinymce-editor
    api-key="my-api-key-here"
  />
  <button @click="addContent">button</button>
</template>

import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue'

export default {
  components: {
    tinymceEditor: Editor
  },
  methods: {
    addContent () {
      tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('<span class="some-class">text</span>');
    }
  }
}
```

Edit:

I also installed `tinymce` using `npm i tinymce --save` and added the import `import tinymce from 'tinymce/tinymce` to the code above. Now I don't get the error `'tinymce' is not defined` anymore, but the editor doesn't appear either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your event handler for the button click, you can call TinyMCE's `.setContent()` method to set editor content.

Here is a demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/set-content-in-tinymce-in-vue-jzciu

Don't forget, `tinymce-vue` doesn't include the code for TinyMCE itself. You'll either have to use an API key (which you can get for free at [tiny.cloud](https://www.tiny.cloud/)) or use a self-hosted installation of TinyMCE. (For more info, see Step 6, here: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/vue/#procedure)

Comment: Hi! I got the API and inserted it in the tinymce element like you said (updated code in question). Still I keep getting `'tinymce' is not defined`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use tinymce in vue with typscritt to set up your content  and avoid the undefined error  you need to import tinyMCE as

```
import { getTinymce } from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue/lib/cjs/main/ts/TinyMCE';
```

Then you can set your content

```
 getTinymce().activeEditor.setContent('coucou');
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally gave up trying to get access to `tinymce` in Vue 3 component. It either `undefined` or if it is not `undefined` - `setContent` command just do nothing - no errors but still no content inserted.
I just used recommended for `"@tinymce/tinymce-vue"` way of data binding using `v-model`
It looks like this:

```
<Editor
      v-model="someLocalVar"
      api-key="no-api-key"
      :init="{
            plugins: 'lists link image table code help wordcount',
       }"
/>
```

then

```
watch(someLocalVar, () => {
        //do whatever you like with your someLocalVar
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to insert content into TinyMCE you should use its APIs to do so:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#setcontent
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#insertcontent

For example:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('<span class="some-class">text</span>');
tinymce.activeEditor.insertContent('<span class="some-class">text</span>');
```

Comment: But how can I access the `tinymce.activeEditor` using tinymce-vue? I don't know how to access this object or how to import it. I just get `'tinymce' is not defined`. I updated the question to show what I did so far...

Comment: Is the `tinymce is not defined` error at runtime or when building the project?  The Vue wrapper code grabs TinyMCE from our cloud platform at runtime so it should be available in the browser.

Comment: I found the problem. Eslint keeps telling it is not defined. But when I disabled Eslint, the application built correctly. Any ideas how can I make vue/eslint see 'tinymce' although it is not defined in code?